# Flutter Expansion tile

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWwle.jpg)I have a nested list as a expantiontile for example :
if I have a list of years each one includes a list of months and into each one there is a list of days
I want when I press on the day number in the list give me a year, the month, and the day I had to choose.

Example:

If I choose the year 2019 the month Feb then day 5 I need when I press on the day or in the expansion tile it well gives my 5 Feb 2019
.
I tried many ways but all time it gave me just the number of the day without the month and year
In the photo u can see wood ward
Into it there many choices : gate 1 , gate 2 and wood ward st
In gate 1 we had many choices such as tower crane or forkleft etc...
I want when i press on a service like tower crane 1
Return all info : woodward , gate 1 , tower crane 1 .
Now it return just tower crane 1

Than you.

Comment: show your code & image/screencast of what is happening now for better understanding the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can try this code hope this will work for you, Thanks  

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class DocumentTile extends StatelessWidget {
    
    
      const DocumentTile({Key ?key,}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, right: 30),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue[800],
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.83,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink,width: 1.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  tilePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 30.0),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
                  trailing: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.49,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 0.5,
                              height: 50,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                            ),
                            const Text(
                              "NUMBER -1",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                            ),
                            const Text(
                              " TITLE",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      /*  Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "guyguy",
                                  ),
                                )),
                            Container(
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                                  iconSize: 25,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.5),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
                                  iconSize: 25,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.5),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )),
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.share_outlined, color: Colors.white),
                                  iconSize: 20,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.5),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                )),
                            Container(
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
                                  iconSize: 25,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.5),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  },
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),*/
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: const Text(
                   "No",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 40.0, right: 30.0, top: 20, bottom: 20),
                      color: Colors.blue[800],
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                           "Subtitle",
                            style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Text(
                            "Subtitle2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Text(
                            "Subtitle3",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Text(
                            "Subtitle4",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: did not work
Anyway, thank you my friend